# React Native TextInput - App crash if fontSize is more then 40

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

So I have 3 screens in my react native app, each screen have a TextInput and a Button.

I use react-navigation and use simple navigate method to go to each screen like below :

```
navigation.navigate('secondScreen');
```

Text Input in all these 3 screens, have a `fontSize: {44}` but for some reasons in the third screen before it render, app will crash with no JS error.

Now if I change the fontsize to : `fontSize: {32}` everything works fine and no problem! It's really don't make any sense. I tried to run the ios project through xcode to see if I get any error, in xcode, as soon as the 3rd screen rendered, I get an error in this file : main.jsbundle line 14 :

`return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));`

Saying : `uncaught exception of type NSException` Which is useless.

Anyone faced to such a weird situation? As long as I reduce the fontSize to less the 40, there is no problem, but as soon as I change to 40 or more the app crashes!

Comment: It is exclusive to IOS ? if so, please remove the android tag. Try in an empty project with react navigation and 3 blank screens . If the issue is reproducible, post it as a bug report in reactnativgation github

Comment: @ValdaXD No it's not just for ios, it happen in both android and ios emulators.